# Plotly Express Scatter plots does not plot full range of x variables

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

I am trying to use Plotly Express to create a scatter plot plotting the average temperature over time in a sample of 75 countries. However, only 34 countries are displayed on the chart, and not all counties are displayed in the legend.

Is there a limit to the amount of variables that can be displayed, or is there some parameter that I'm missing. My code is below for reference;

```
fig=px.scatter(df, x= 'Country', y='Temperature', animation_frame='YR',
           animation_group='Country',size='Temperature', color='Country', 
           hover_name='Country',width=1000, height=600, 
           range_y=[2,35])
```

Full code

```
!pip install plotly_express
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(75, 1)))
df= df.rename(columns={0: "Temperature"}) 
df['Country']=['United States','Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria','American Samoa','Andorra','Angola','Anguilla','Antarctica','Antigua And Barbuda',
         'Argentina','Armenia','Aruba','Australia','Austria','Azerbaijan','Bahamas','Bahrain','Bangladesh','Barbados','Belarus','Belgium','Belize',
         'Benin','Bermuda','Bhutan','Bolivia','Bosnia And Herzegowina','Botswana','Bouvet Island','Brazil','Brunei Darussalam','Bulgaria',
         'Burkina Faso','Burundi','Cambodia','Cameroon','Canada','Cape Verde','Cayman Islands','Central African Rep','Chad','Chile','China',
         'Christmas Island','Cocos Islands','Colombia','Comoros','Congo','Cook Islands','Costa Rica','Cote D`ivoire','Croatia','Cuba','Cyprus',
         'Czech Republic','Denmark','Djibouti','Dominica','Dominican Republic','East Timor','Ecuador','Egypt','El Salvador','Equatorial Guinea',
         'Eritrea','Estonia','Ethiopia','Falkland Islands (Malvinas)','Faroe Islands','Finland','France','French Guiana','French Polynesia',
         'French S. Territories']
df['YR']=[2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,
      2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,
      2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,2015, 2016,2017, 2018, 2019,
      2015, 2016,2017,2015, 2016,2017,2015, 2016,2017,2015, 2016,2016,2017,2015, 2016]

fig=px.scatter(df, x= 'Country', y='Temperature', animation_frame='YR',
           animation_group='Country',size='Temperature', color='Country', 
           hover_name='Country',width=1000, height=600, 
           range_y=[2,35])
fig
```

Comment: I would try scaling back on the fig= code that you are showing and see if defaults kick in.  I think you are not getting an answer because most people would need your entire code (everything, df source and all) to work it out.

Comment: Thanks @gerald, taking out the specifications for the width worked and I am now able to scroll through all the counties in the graph, but still can't fit all the values on the same view. I've added the full code as per your recommendation

Comment: The y-axis range setting is getting in the way, isn't it?

Comment: The animation slider and the x-axis labels are interfering with each other and can be avoided with the following settings. `fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t'] = 150;fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']['t'] = 150` See this:[Plotly: How to change time widgets position?](Plotly: How to change time widgets position?)

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, the animation slider looks a lot better now and removing the  y-axis range setting helped, as I am able to see about 58 of the counties listed but still not the full range. I am using Jupiter notebook not sure if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x-axis ticks were thinned out so they were not all displayed. if you give all countries in a list in `tickvals`, they will all be displayed.

```
fig=px.scatter(df, x='Country',
               y='Temperature',
               animation_frame='YR',
               animation_group='Country',
               size='Temperature',
               color='Country',
               hover_name='Country',
               width=1000,
               height=600,
               #range_y=[2,35]
              )

fig['layout']['sliders'][0]['pad']['t'] = 150
fig['layout']['updatemenus'][0]['pad']['t'] = 150
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    showlegend=True
)
fig.update_xaxes(type='category', tickvals=df['Country'].tolist())
fig.show()
```

[image]